# Changing formats of number with currency and percentage

Tags: vba, ms-word

I only know how to do it when I am on MS Excel but with MS Word I am a bit new.

I have this kind of Data:

For nos.:

```
 $90,000 <should be>>> 90 000 $
 $50,500 <should be>>> 50 500 $
 $45,200 <should be>>> 45 200 $
```

For percent:

```
50.25% <should be>>> 50,25 %
45.45% <should be>>> 45,45 %
35.05% <should be>>> 35,05 %
```

In excel I could do this in format cell using the custom option "**# ##0_) $;Red**" will give me the output of "**$90,000 >> 90 000 $**". But this was in Excel I am going to work on Word file. As for percent I still don't have an idea.
Was there a way to do this in MSWORD?

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for a code solution, or what? Give us some more background on where these numbers are coming from, how they're being put in the document, at what point the formatting should take place...

Comment: The data was formatted as table in word

Comment: So, you have a table in Word that contains such numbers and you want code to format them after-the-fact? Please confirm that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you help [this link](http://www.gmayor.com/formatting_word_fields.htm)